# backslash in dictionary in julia

Tags: julia

I can quickly create a dictionary in julia via:

```
julia> d = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2 ]
Dict{Char,Int64} with 2 entries:
  'b' => 2
  'a' => 1
```

Now, I want the backslash character as a key in my dictionary. This results in an error because it will escape the `'`. Instead, I try to escape the `\` with another. This doesn't cause an error, but doens't give me the correct result either.

```
julia> d = ['\\' => 3]
Dict{Char,Int64} with 1 entry:
  '\\' => 3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Also note that this is now deprecated syntax.  `WARNING: deprecated syntax "[a=>b, ...]".  Use "Dict(a=>b, ...)" instead.`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How would you use a dict comprehension with this new syntax?

Comment: Interestingly, `Dict` comprehensions are **not** deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the correct value.  Julia generally tries to [`show`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/io-network/#Base.show) values in the same way that you type them, whereas it will [`print`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/io-network/#Base.print) them in their "canonical" form (without special syntaxes).

```
julia> show('\\')
'\\'
julia> print('\\')
\
julia> hex('\\')
"5c"
shell> man ascii | grep 5c
     58  X    59  Y    5a  Z    5b  [    5c  \    5d  ]    5e  ^    5f  _
```